# How to save the position of views components?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I have 10 frameLayouts in LinearLayout. In my app I can move these frames, but if I close it, position of my frames didn't save. And if I open app again I see default position of my frames? 
How can I save position? Help!! 
P.S. In my app I use sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store stuff in memory and restore them at later time:
[Android docs for SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

**Example - Storing and restoring an integer called position:**

```
    int position = 0;

    //get the SharedPreferences for "yourContextName", which you need to replace it with you context name
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("yourContextName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      /* --------------- Storing data -------------------- */

     //Get editor for writing data to memory
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    //Add an integer to editor
    editor.putInt("position", position);

    //Must commit or else the data will NOT be stored
    editor.commit();


    /* ---------------- Retrievig data ------------------ */

    //Retrievig an integer from pref with tag "position" (-1 is the default value)
    int retInt = pref.getInt("position", -1);
```

Comment: How can I use this example for my situation: in ScrollView> in LinearLayout: 10 FrameLayouts which I move? I need to save postition for my FrameLayouts in LinearLayout. I found .getVerticalScrollbarPosition only. Is this what I need?